# How to rows from an numpy array using single indices and a range of indices

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Imagine, I have a 2D NumPy array X with 100 columns and 100 rows. Then, how can I extract the following rows and column using indexing?

```
rows= 1, 5, 15, 16 to 35, 45, 55 to 75
columns = 1, 2, 10 to 30, 42, 50
```

I know in MATLAB, we can do this using

```
X([1,5,15,16:35,45,55:75],[1,2,10:30,42,50]).
```

How can we do this in Python?

Comment: Does the MATLAB give a block of values?  A set of rows and a set of columns?  `numpy` handles the block versus `sub2ind` cases differently.

Comment: yes, as I mentioned in the question, we can extract a set of rows (say indices, idxR) and a set of columns (idxC) simultaneously from an array X in MATLAB using X([idxR], [idxC]).

Comment: Use `np.ix_(list1, list2)` to see the kinds arrays needed to index a block.  To understand `arr[ idx1, idx2]` in `numpy` you have to understand how `idx1` broadcasts with `idx2`.  These are the same rules as used when adding two arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.r_`:

```
rows = np.r_[1, 5, 15, 16:35, 45, 55:75]
cols = np.r_[1, 2, 10:30, 42, 50]

X[rows,cols]
```

Note that, in Python, `16:35` usually does not include `35`. You may want to do `16:36` if you want row `35` as well.